# BeautifulSoup - how do i scrape multiple links to then scrape contents of links

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do a scrape where the landing page has various links (the 5 sub categories at the top):
https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d410_New_Browning_over___under_shotguns.html

Within each of these categories are a list of products https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d411_Browning_B725_Shotguns.html

Each product listed has a link to get further details (a direct link to the product as an individual page) https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/p74600_Browning-B725-Sporter-over-_-under.html

The scrape I've put together so far will get as far as creating a list of all the individual page links required.  But when I try to loop each individual product link for data,  I cant seem to get the BeautifulSoup to map the data from those links. Its as though it stays on the previous page (if you will).
What am I missing to allow for that second "bounce" to the "product_link" address (eg https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/p74600_Browning-B725-Sporter-over-_-under.html) and allow me to scrape the data from there?  I had thought I might need to add a time.sleep(5) timer to allow for all to load but still getting nothing.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import math 
import requests 
import shutil 
import csv 
import pandas 
import numpy as np 
from pandas import DataFrame 
import re
import os 
import urllib.request as urllib2 
import locale 
import json 
from selenium import webdriver 
import lxml.html 
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select  
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8" 


#selenium requests 

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/admin/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d410_New_Browning_over___under_shotguns.html") 
time.sleep(2) 

all_Outlinks=[] 
all_links=[]

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="lxml") 
submenuFind = soup.find("div", "idx2Submenu") 
submenuItems = submenuFind.find_all("li", "GC34 idx2Sub") 

for submenuItem in submenuItems: 
    for link in submenuItem.select('a[href]'): 
        all_Outlinks.append("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/" + link['href']) 
#print(all_Outlinks) 

for a_link in all_Outlinks:
    res = requests.get(a_link) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser') 
    pageLinkDivs = soup.find_all("div", "column full")
    for pageLinkDiv in pageLinkDivs:
        for pageLink in pageLinkDiv.select('a[href]'):
            all_links.append("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/" + pageLink['href'])
#print(all_links)
            
for product_link in all_links:
    time.sleep(5)
    resSecond = requests.get(product_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resSecond.text, 'html.parser')
    model = soup.find("div", "GC75 ProductChoiceName")
    print(model)
```

PS Apologies for the additional imports.  They are copy and paste from a previous script to be removed once confirmed not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That info is pulled dynamically from a script tag when using browser. As using requests this will not be in the location you might be looking. Instead, pull that info from the script tag.

In this case, I pull all the info related to a given model that is within the script and generate a dataframe. I convert the string inside the script tag to a python object with `ast`. I add the product url and product title to the dataframe.

Each df is added to a list which is converted to a final dataframe. As I don't know what final header names would be required I have left some with their default names.

I have added in handling for the case(s) where there are no model options listed for the given product.

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import math 
import requests 
import shutil 
import csv 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import re
import os 
import urllib.request as urllib2 
import locale 
import json 
from selenium import webdriver 
import lxml.html 
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select  
import ast

os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8" 

#selenium requests 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/admin/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d410_New_Browning_over___under_shotguns.html") 
time.sleep(2) 

all_Outlinks=[] 
all_links=[]

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="lxml") 
submenuFind = soup.find("div", "idx2Submenu") 
submenuItems = submenuFind.find_all("li", "GC34 idx2Sub") 

for submenuItem in submenuItems: 
    for link in submenuItem.select('a[href]'): 
        all_Outlinks.append("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/" + link['href']) 
#print(all_Outlinks) 

with requests.Session() as s:
    
    for a_link in all_Outlinks:
        res = requests.get(a_link) 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser') 
        pageLinkDivs = soup.find_all("div", "column full")
        for pageLinkDiv in pageLinkDivs:
            for pageLink in pageLinkDiv.select('a[href]'):
                all_links.append("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/" + pageLink['href'])
    
    results = []
    
    for product_link in all_links:
        # print(product_link)
        resSecond = s.get(product_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(resSecond.text, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.select_one('.ProductTitle').text
        
        try:
            df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(re.search(r'(\[\[.*\]\])', soup.select_one('.ProductOptions script').string).groups(0)[0]))
            df.iloc[:, -1] = product_link
        except:
            placeholder = ['No options listed'] * 8
            placeholder.append(product_link)
            df = pd.DataFrame([placeholder])
        
        df.insert(0, 'title', title)
        
        #print(df) # add headers you care about to df or do that at end on full list
        results.append(df)
final = pd.concat(results) # or add header here
print(final)
```

---

You could then look at speeding/tidying things up:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import pandas as pd
import re
import os 
import locale 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import ast
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def get_models_df(product_link):
    res = requests.get(product_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    title = soup.select_one('.ProductTitle').text

    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(re.search(r'(\[\[.*\]\])', soup.select_one('.ProductOptions script').string).groups(0)[0]))
        df.iloc[:, -1] = product_link
    except:
        placeholder = ['No options listed'] * 8
        placeholder.append(product_link)
        df = pd.DataFrame([placeholder])

    df.insert(0, 'title', title)
    return(df)


def get_all_pages(a_link):
    res = requests.get(a_link) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml') 
    all_links = ["https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/" + i['href'] for i in soup.select('.center-content > a')]   
    return all_links

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8" 

    #selenium requests 
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/admin/chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d410_New_Browning_over___under_shotguns.html") 
    all_outlinks = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".idx2Submenu a")))]
    browser.quit()
    
    with Pool(cpu_count()-1) as p:

        nested_links = p.map(get_all_pages , all_outlinks)
        flat_list = [link for links in nested_links for link in links]   
        results = p.map(get_models_df, flat_list)
        final = pd.concat(results)
        #print(final)
        final.to_csv('guninfo.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index = False)
```

---

So I said I would have a look at the other requested items and they are indeed available just with `requests`. Some things that needed handling:

1. Different headers present for different products; some missing headers
2. Some unicode characters (there are still some encoding things to look at)
3. Handling cases where description missing
4. Handling the more section
5. Updating certain output values so Excel doesn't convert them to dates
6. Handling of header `nan`

TODO:

1. One of the functions has now become a rabid monster and needs re-factoring into smaller friendly function calls.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import pandas as pd
import re
import os 
import locale 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import ast
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import numpy as np
import unicodedata

def get_models_df(product_link):

    resSecond = requests.get(product_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resSecond.text, 'lxml')
    title = soup.select_one('.ProductTitle').text

    try:
        df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(re.search(r'(\[\[.*\]\])', soup.select_one('.ProductOptions script').string).groups(0)[0]))
        
    except:
        placeholder = ['No options listed'] * 8
        df = pd.DataFrame([placeholder])
    
    df.insert(0, 'title', title)
    df['price'] = ' '.join([soup.select_one("[property='product:price:amount']")['content'], 
                   soup.select_one("[property='product:price:currency']")['content']])
    df['weight'] = ' '.join([soup.select_one("[property='product:weight:value']")['content'], 
                    soup.select_one("[property='product:weight:units']")['content']])

    output_headers = ['Action frame', 'Barrel','Barrel finish','Barrel length', 
                      'Barrel length (mm-inch)','Buttstock','Calibre','Chokes','Code',
                      'Drop at comb','Drop at heel','Forearm','Length','N/A','Notes',
                      'Options','Packaging','Sights','Stock style','Top rib','Weight','Wood','Wood grade'
                     ]
    
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns = output_headers)])
    
    try:
        description_table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('.ProductDetailedDescription table, table')))[0].transpose()
        description_table.dropna(axis=0, how='all',inplace=True)
        headers = list(description_table.iloc[0,:])
        headers[:] = ['N/A' if pd.isnull(np.array([header], dtype=object)) else header for header in headers]
        
        for number, header in enumerate(headers):
            temp = header.lower()
            value = description_table.iloc[1, number]
            if temp == 'calibre':
                df[header] = "'" + value
            elif  temp == 'top rib' and 'mm' not in value:
                df[header] = value + 'mm'
            else:
                df[header] = value
     
    except:
        pass # no table
        
    description = soup.select_one('#ProductDetailsTab [title=More]')
    
    if description is None:
        desc = 'N/A'
    else:
        desc = '. '.join([i.text for i in soup.select('.ProductDescription li, .ProductDescription span') if i.text !=''])
        if desc == '':
            desc = soup.select_one('.ProductIntroduction').get_text()

    df['desc'] = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', desc)   
    df['product_link'] = product_link
    
    return(df)

def get_all_pages(a_link):
        
    res = requests.get(a_link) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml') 
    all_links = ["https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/" + i['href'] for i in soup.select('.center-content > a')]

    return all_links

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8" 

    #selenium requests 
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()# executable_path='C:/Users/admin/chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d410_New_Browning_over___under_shotguns.html") 
    all_outlinks = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".idx2Submenu a")))]
    browser.quit()

    with Pool(cpu_count()-1) as p:

        nested_links = p.map(get_all_pages , all_outlinks)
        flat_list = [link for links in nested_links for link in links]
        results = p.map(get_models_df, flat_list)
        final = pd.concat(results)
        #print(final)
        final.to_csv('guninfo.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index = False)
```

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for having a look.  I'm assuming you you getting the information from the script which is found on the product listings page  The problem here is they dont contain all the information which is in the products individual page (description etc)  Do you know of a way in which the version i have could potentially work?

Comment: your question didn't request this info

Comment: In a round about way it did "What am I missing to allow for that second "bounce" to the "product_link" address (eg https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/p74600_Browning-B725-Sporter-over-_-under.html) and allow me to scrape the data from there?" the data being the inclusive of all product data on the individual products page - sorry if i was not completely clear in my question

Comment: Sorry. I was just re-reading and saw that. I will need to revisit after work. I suspect this will require selenium but won't know until I revisit.

Comment: Exactly which items do you need from each product page?

Comment: that was my thinking also with the selenium.  I'm still looking at it so if I come to an answer i'll update.

Comment: Title, Desc, Price, Model More Info (when applicable) , - The data itself is not really important as i can work at collecting that.  Its more the ability to get to the data.  after that i should be OK.

Comment: Hi,  Made a bit more movement on the data.  Will update once think can get what is required.  You were correct with the Selenium

Comment: I don't think the adaptation is difficult as you have the product url list. You just need to .get to those instead and have a custom function which parses that page (possibly with a wait condition and that returns a row (list) which it appends to a global list. That global list gets a row/list (each item you want from a page is a column in that row) appended from each product page visited. Convert whole thing to df at end.

Comment: No,  Turns out it was very straight forward.  Was just missing what was staring me straight in the face.  I'll update

Comment: So, I had a look and it is possible to get all that data with requests. Bit of a headache working it out (but you will face similar issues with selenium). Updated answer to show you one way.

Comment: Hi @QHarr - I didnt see your reply until this morning.  I will give it a run through and see what its like.  Looks to grab a lot of the information which would be very useful to me so if it is what it looks to be ill mark yours as the answer rather than my own.  Thanks for the time spent on it.

Comment: Did this work as expected or did I miss something?

Comment: hi @QHarr no it works fantastically.  I've been distracted with other projects.  I'm only coming back to this again this week with fresh eyes.  I threw yours into python tonight and im blown away at what its doing compared to mine and how quickly and seamlessly it does it.  makes me feel like I'm wasting my time when i see what you've done there.

Comment: It is good to look at different ways of doing it. Multi-processing plays nicely with pandas.

Comment: what you've done here is way beyond my thinking and understanding of this scraping stuff.  I'm only at it a few months on and off.  I've to build a scrape to collect all the New firearms from this website and the deeper i go the more complicated it becomes.  Its such a messy website for scraping data from.  There is no set design for each new firearm - there could be maybe 10 different methods of listings designs.  every time i get so far i hit another setback

Comment: It took some thinking to get to the point above due to the difference between pages. It's a balance between what you will learn from the challenge of these pages and the frustration. You've done well for only a few months! One particular challenge is the `output_headers` as I didn't realise how much variation there is for specifications. You will likely encounter a lot more meaning you will either need to determine a core set and handle when not present, or map out the whole lot and fill with placeholders where not present. The latter is what I chose for the pages I came across.

Answer (score 1):

As QHarr pointed out Selenium was the answer.  This gave me the direction to look at it with different eyes and allowed me to find the answer.

I'm posting as my answer but crediting @QHarr with the work based on work provided previous and the ongoing assistance to help lead to the solution.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import math
import requests
import shutil
import csv
import pandas
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import urllib.request as urllib2
import locale
import json
from selenium import webdriver
import lxml.html
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select 
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"

#selenium requests
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/andrew.glass/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d410_New_Browning_over___under_shotguns.html") 
time.sleep(2) 

all_Outlinks=[] 
all_links=[]

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="lxml") 
submenuFind = soup.find("div", "idx2Submenu") 
submenuItems = submenuFind.find_all("li", "GC34 idx2Sub") 

for submenuItem in submenuItems: 
    for link in submenuItem.select('a[href]'): 
        all_Outlinks.append("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/" + link['href']) 
#print(all_Outlinks) 

for a_link in all_Outlinks:
    res = requests.get(a_link) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser') 
    pageLinkDivs = soup.find_all("div", "column full")
    for pageLinkDiv in pageLinkDivs:
        for pageLink in pageLinkDiv.select('a[href]'):
            all_links.append("https://mcavoyguns.co.uk/contents/en-uk/" + pageLink['href'])
#print(all_links)
            
for product_link in all_links:
    
    browser.get(product_link)
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
    model = soup.find("div", "GC65 ProductOptions")
    modelFind = soup.find('select', attrs={'name': re.compile('model')})
    modelList = [x['origvalue'][:14] for x in modelFind.find_all('option')[1:]]
    print(modelList)
```

Model print still a bit messy but can clean it up once get all requirements gathered.